# Macbook pro doesn't work, only powers up

Tags: macbook-pro

I was using my macbook pro a little while back, and all of a sudden the screen freezes.

So I turn it off by clicking the power button until it shuts off, and the next time I click it, the screen stays black, the keyboard doesn't light up, and only the light at the bottom right of the laptop stays on, and doesn't blink when I supposedly close the lid and put it on sleep mode.

I can't seem to open it in target mode with a thunderbolt cable connected to an iMac, and I don't know what's wrong with it, so any suggestions? The Apple people keep telling me that if it's a hardware problem, I'd pay for a certain solution, and if it was software, I'd pay even higher for another solution--and there's no guarantee that it'll actually work.

Comment: Probably wont work, but have you tried holding down Command, Option, P + R while powering up?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a Mac but basic 'PC hardware troubleshooting' will work regardless of the make/model.

First check would be - is it still under any hardware warranty? If so get them involved before doing anything which may void it.

Next would be gaining the assistance of someone (friend/paid repair center) to diagnose the actual fault with it, from there you can gather the required details and pricing of any repairs.

From an experienced hardware support background the fault reported sounds like it could be memory, motherboard or power supply related. Further troubleshooting would be required to determine which of these (or other) fault is the exact cause.